# Steam shop - Do not show 'In library' games

Tags: steam

Is there a way to stop Steam showing games you already own in the store page? 
I have looked through help and searched the net but I can't find such an option.
I own a lot of games and it would be much easier to browse if I could do this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this with the Steam website, and it is unlikely that any userscript (such as Enhanced Steam) will be able to do this either, due to the way the site works.

Sorry!